# How to automatically click "update" button in asp.net control?

Tags: asp.net, updatecommand, server-side-controls

I used asp.net server side control to display and modify data in database, the control is just like this one:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx
what I want to do is after I click the "edit" button it will display  a "edit" ui, and I want everytime I modify the data in the text box, asp.net will automatically click the "update" button for me to update the data i entered.

I tried to call the event handler, but failed.
There is a update command in asp.net, and how to programmatically call it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can get the event refernce via this code

```
string postbackEvent = this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.button,"");
```

the postbackEvent will contains a __doPostback() function, which will invoke the button click in the server side. Assign this to some event, like onBlur of textbox.

```
this.txtSample.Attributes.Add("onBlur",postbackEvent);
```

Comment: Can I just directly execute the postbackEvent ?what function should I call ?

Comment: You will get the Post back even in the postbackEvent variable. And I am not sure it is recommended method or not, but try using Eval() method.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have to use the onTextChanged event of your TextBox control.

Answer (score 0):

Set the autopostback attribute to "true"

```
<asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="True" ID="somethingID" OnTextChanged="CallSomeMethod" />
```

Look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx